# How can I check if a glm / lm of statsmodels is converged or not?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Where can I check if the regression fit is converged? After I set `.fit(maxiter=7)` I would expect it doesn't converge. But it doesn't trigger any warnings. So I am wondering in generally how I can check if a model fit is convergent or not?

This is the source code: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/genmod/generalized_linear_model.html#GLM.fit

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/genmod/generalized_linear_model.py

Does it mean it never produces any warning message if the fit doesn't even converge?

I raised an issue in github.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1844

If it is really because of the source code, I will close the question.

Comment: In principle, you could check the derivative of the likelihood or check how much progress is made by the last iteration.

Comment: might be better answered in scicomp.SE

Comment: The results has the number of iterations. If the number of iterations is equal to maxiter, then the optimization terminated because of maxiter and not because it is converged, except in the unlikely case that the optimization converged at the `maxiter` iteration.

Answer (score 4):

All of the maximum likelihood models have a converged flag in the `mle_retvals`. GLM doesn't have this yet.

The easiest way is to check is to do exactly what is done in the source there. Import `_check_convergence`, the convergence criterion is already attached, so is the iteration, and you know the `tol`. If you file an issue on github (there might be one already), it'll get added. Of course, this would be trivial to add, so PRs welcome.